# Convert Swift Function to Objective-C SubstringToIndex

Tags: objective-c, swift, bluetooth, substring, character

The swift function below hides the key(s) that is pressed on a Bluetooth device display, I'm trying to write this function in Objective-C, however I'm struggling to write characters.count & substringToIndex as shown below in Objective-C, can anyone please help me convert this to Objective-C?

```
var msg = ""

func captin(leader: CaptinShip!, keyPressed keyCode: UInt) {
    print(String(format: "keyPressed: %d (0x%02X)", keyCode, keyCode))

    if keyCode == 0 {
        msg += "*"
    }
    if keyCode == 13 && msg.characters.count > 0 {
        msg = msg.substringToIndex(msg.endIndex.advancedBy(-1))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that your `msg` will be a `NSString` object. If so this should do it:

```
if (keyCode == 0) {
    msg = [msg stringByAppendingString:@"*"];
}

if (keyCode == 13 && [msg length] > 0) {
    msg = [msg substringToIndex:[msg length] - 2];
}
```

But you might consider creating another check on the length of `msg`, since it will crash if the `[msg length] - 2` is out of bounds on the `msg` length.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick, Thanks. Can I ask, would you know how I could repeat the * in Objective-C? Like the Swift code above msg += "*".

Comment: No problem! I've edited the answer and added the appending of the `*`.

Comment: Thanks for that, been a great help